# Unconstrained lifetime error when implementing Index trait

Tags: rust

I have a struct that owns a `HashMap<String, String>`,

```
struct Test {
    data: HashMap<String, String>,
}
```

I am trying to implement the `Index` trait for this type to map to the `Index` implementation of the hashmap (there's other logic involved so I cannot expose the hashmap).

This works if I am just getting a reference to the value in the hashmap:

```
impl<'b> Index<&'b str> for Test {
    type Output = String;
    fn index(&self, k: &'b str) -> &String {
        self.data.get(k).unwrap()
    }
}
```

However, I want to get `&Option<&String>` out of it, like `data.get()`. So I tried this:

```
impl<'b, 'a> Index<&'b str> for Test {
    type Output = Option<&'a String>;
    fn index(&'a self, k: &'b str) -> &Option<&'a String> {
        &self.data.get(k)
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> <anon>:8:10
  |
8 | impl<'b, 'a> Index<&'b str> for Test {
  |          ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

I understand the "`unconstrained lifetime parameter` in `'a`". Now `'a` is the lifetime of `Test` itself, so I want (I think) `where 'Self: 'a` (so `self` lives at least as long as `'a` ) . I cannot seem to figure this out for `Index` impl? I tried some things with adding `PhantomData` to my `Test`. But I am not getting anywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: What you're trying is not possible. `index()` will always return a reference and you can't return a reference to the function local `Option<T>`, because it doesn't live long enough. Apart from that, I *think* (just a wild guess) that the lifetime issue is actually the same as with *streaming iterators*. If that's the case, Rust's type system is not powerful enough to express this yet. But anyway, you don't want to return an `Option<T>` via `index()`, as it's expected to panic on an invalid index. Just write a `get()` method, like the hashmap does. I hope that maybe helped.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct. Semantically, `Index` should panic, so  `get()` is the better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you won't be able to do exactly what you want.  But, what it seems like you really want is to replicate `HashMap`'s `get` method. So I would suggest either writing your own, or implmenting `Deref` (and *not* `DerefMut`) to give the struct's owner *immutable* access directly to the internal `HashMap`.  Hopefully that means the user can't mess up your struct's internal logic.  Keep in mind that if you do both then `Deref` will not be used to called `HashMap::get` because `Test::get` will be available.

```
struct FooMap {
    data: HashMap<String, String>
}
```

Replicating `get`:

```
impl FooMap {
    pub fn get(&self, index: &str) -> Option<&String> { self.data.get(index) }
}
```

Using `Deref`:

```
impl Deref for FooMap {
    type Target = HashMap<String, String>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target { &self.data }
}
```

[Example code on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c27981ecba3bc60fbc90e0cf2f26134a&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: The logic is a little more involved, so the look up may not actually be on a hash in some cases; anyway this is what I was using - it saves having to write boiler plate just to map the look up onto the internal container.